# Display current branch name in Eclipse/Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a project set-up within Eclipse which is linked to our SVN repository using Subclipse.  Is there a way to display the name of the current branch I'm in next to project.  I'm sure I've seen this before but it's not there now and I can't find out how to switch this feature on anywhere.  Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

By default subclipse will present the current branch info (in square brackets) next to the project name inside the **Package Explorer** view.

This is customizable inside the ***Window -> Preferences*** window under the following location:

***Team -> SVN -> Label decorations (Text tab) -> Project Format***

If you somehow lost your default setting, here it is:

**{dirty_flag}{name} [{url_short}]**

Comment: Thanks Wojtek.  That wasn't the issue but through looking at that I found the problem.  

**General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations**  

My "SVN" checkbox was unchecked.  Think this must have occurred when I uninstalled my previous version of subclipse.  When I installed the latest version it clearly never rechecked that box.

Comment: OK, glad I could be of any help then.

Comment: I also had same issue (SVN checkbox was unchecked). Thanks for saving my day.